# golang tabwriter does not format appropriately

Tags: go

I am following the common [pattern](https://blog.el-chavez.me/2019/05/05/golang-tabwriter-aligned-text/) about `go`'s [`tabwriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/tabwriter/)

where the relevant writer is initialized and used to print formatted output to stdout.

Here is my code snippet:

```
w := tabwriter.NewWriter(os.Stdout, 20, 30, 1, '\t', tabwriter.AlignRight)


for _, v := range listProjectsResponse.Projects {
    parent := fmt.Sprintf("projects/%s/locations/-", v.ProjectId)
    resp, err := containerService.Projects.Locations.Clusters.List(parent).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf(err.Error())
    }
    if len(resp.Clusters) > 0 {
        fmt.Println("---------------------------------------------------------")
        fmt.Printf("Project\t%s\n", v.ProjectId)
        fmt.Println("---------------------------------------------------------")
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Cluster\t\tNode Count\n")
        //w.Flush()
        for _, p := range resp.Clusters {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s\t%d\t", p.Name, p.CurrentNodeCount)
            //w.Flush()
        }
        w.Flush()
        fmt.Printf("\n")
    }
}
```

However it seems that the common distance between column is not being respected, as shown in the following output:

```
Project my-project-1
---------------------------------------------------------
Cluster         Node Count
my-cluster-1  3
---------------------------------------------------------
Project my-project-2
---------------------------------------------------------
Cluster         Node Count
my-newest-project-1       2
---------------------------------------------------------
Project my-project-3
---------------------------------------------------------
Cluster         Node Count
anothercluster 1
```

Why isn't each column keeping a fixed width (which I assume based on the initialization of the relevant writer should be 30 chars long?).
Where is the misconfiguration in the above code?

**edit**:

What I would expect, is that each column has a fixed with, i.e. the second column (the node count) always appears in the same position (column)  as in

```
Project my-project-1
---------------------------------------------------------
Cluster         Node Count
my-cluster-1              3
---------------------------------------------------------
Project my-project-2
---------------------------------------------------------
Cluster          Node Count
my-newest-project-1       2
---------------------------------------------------------
Project my-project-3
---------------------------------------------------------
Cluster         Node Count
anothercluster           1
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I have updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you initialize the tabwriter like this:

```
w := tabwriter.NewWriter(os.Stdout, 20, 30, 1, '\t', tabwriter.AlignRight)
```

2nd argument is the min cell width: `20`, 3rd is the tab width: `30`. This should correspond to a value of a printed tab width. Most systems use 4 or 8 width for a printed tab. And next argument tells to use tabs for alignment. And in this case the tabwriter assumes that 1 printed tab occupies 30 spaces (that's what the previous argument tells), which results in inaccurate calculations.
This problem can simply be eliminated by using spaces instead of tabs for padding.

Next: you have to use tabs after the last cell, else the tabwriter won't know it's the end of the cell and could not make them properly right-aligned.

Going forward: inside the cluster loop you should use newline characters, because although in your example there is only a single cluster for each project, but if you'd have more, they would be printed in a single line.

And a tip: you may use `tabwriter.Debug` flag to have cell borders printed.

Ok, let's see your example, changed to be runnable on the Go Playground. I'm gonna use the following test data:

```
type Cluster struct {
    Name             string
    CurrentNodeCount int
}

type Project struct {
    ProjectId string
    Clusters  []Cluster
}

projects := []Project{
    {
        ProjectId: "p1",
        Clusters: []Cluster{
            {Name: "p1c1", CurrentNodeCount: 2},
            {Name: "p1c2", CurrentNodeCount: 3},
        },
    },
    {
        ProjectId: "p2",
        Clusters: []Cluster{
            {Name: "p2c1", CurrentNodeCount: 4},
            {Name: "p2c2", CurrentNodeCount: 5},
        },
    },
}
```

And the processing / formatting code:

```
w := tabwriter.NewWriter(os.Stdout, 20, 8, 1, ' ',
    tabwriter.Debug|tabwriter.AlignRight)

for _, v := range projects {
    if len(v.Clusters) == 0 {
        continue
    }
    fmt.Println("---------------------------------------------------------")
    fmt.Printf("Project\t%s\n", v.ProjectId)
    fmt.Println("---------------------------------------------------------")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Cluster\tNode Count\t\n")
    for _, p := range v.Clusters {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s\t%d\t\n", p.Name, p.CurrentNodeCount)
    }
    w.Flush()
    fmt.Printf("\n")
}
```

Which then outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ezrS5dmrdoO)):

```
---------------------------------------------------------
Project p1
---------------------------------------------------------
             Cluster|          Node Count|
                p1c1|                   2|
                p1c2|                   3|

---------------------------------------------------------
Project p2
---------------------------------------------------------
             Cluster|          Node Count|
                p2c1|                   4|
                p2c2|                   5|
```

It might not be a good idea to mix "regular" `fmt` calls and tabwriter, both printing to the standard output.

Also note that tabwriter can easily be substituted with just simple `fmt` formatted printing:

```
for _, v := range projects {
    if len(v.Clusters) == 0 {
        continue
    }
    fmt.Println("---------------------------------------------------------")
    fmt.Printf("Project\t%s\n", v.ProjectId)
    fmt.Println("---------------------------------------------------------")
    fmt.Printf("%20s|%20s|\n", "Cluster", "Node Count")
    for _, p := range v.Clusters {
        fmt.Printf("%20s|%20d|\n", p.Name, p.CurrentNodeCount)
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n")
}
```

The above code will print the same without using tabwriter (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3xRuKgoQXsZ)).